# jQuery - How can i dynamically add a list item to an unordered list?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors, html-lists

Seems like a simple thing to do (although im still learning the ins and outs of jQuery).

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="fbsignup">
    <div class="message messageerror"> 
       <strong>There were errors with your registration:</strong> 
          <ul></ul> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Here's my (attempted) jQuery:

```
// Check Required Fields.
$('#fbsignup input.required').each(function () {
   if ($(this).val().trim() == '') {
      $(this).next('em').html('*').show();
      $('#fbsignup .message ul').add('li').html('Fields marked with * are required.');
    }
});
```

And this is what it is doing to the DOM:

```
<div class="message messageerror"> 
   <strong>There were errors with your registration:</strong> 
      <ul>Fields marked with * are required.</ul> 
</div>
```

It's adding the text to the inner html. I want it to add a `<li>` element with the inner html of what i set - i thought this is how chaining works?

This is the HTML i **want** to end up with:

```
<div class="message messageerror"> 
   <strong>There were errors with your registration:</strong> 
      <ul>
         <li>Fields marked with * are required.</li> 
      </ul>
</div>
```

I also tried this:

```
$('#fbsignup .message ul').add('<li>Fields marked with * are required.</li>');
```

Which does absolutely nothing.

What am i missing? Is the `.add` function not the right thing to use here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `.appendTo(...)` for this style.

`$("<li/>").appendTo("#fbsignup .message ul").html("Fields marked with * are required.");​`

[Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/F9Lct/1/)

Comment: Nice. I like this better because you can chain on selectors (.html). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me seems to be that you are using a function called .add() <del>*and I don't think there is such function*</del> -wrong.
Likely you can use .append() to do your will http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=append =)

A good general rule for me is to try stuff beforehand on the Firebug console (over FireFox)

Comment: .add is certainly a function (http://api.jquery.com/add/). i also tried append, does same thing (adds html, not element with html)

Comment: OK - got it working with .append('<li>foo</li>'). shame the parameter is only content and not an actual dom element (e.g .append('li').html('foo'). anyway, all good. thanks

Comment: hehe Shame on me, .add is a function, it just that the API search didn't point it out for me :P

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$('#fbsignup .message ul li').add`

Comment: selector wont return anything as there is no li element (yet - that is the whole point)